# How can I restrict URL shortcuts on my website?

Tags: php, html, css

What I want is rather simple but I cannot figure it out. I want that if someone tries to access any of the webpages directly on my website then he/she must be redirected to the home page of the website.

For Example : Someone tries to access www.domain-name.com/aboutus he gets re directed to www.domain-name.com/

Comment: Many ways to do what you're asking for, please provide details as to why you want to do this.

Comment: Check referrer for example, though it is not reliable.

Comment: It is client's demand because he doesn't want any visitor to directly access site's pages. If anybody tries to access page directly then user will be redirected to home page.

Answer (score 1):

you can check referrer to block any direct access to your website.
include this code in every page of your website.

```
<?php
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$url = "http://www.domain-name.com";
// $url is the main url of your website
if($ref==$url){}else{
header("location:$url");
}
?>
```

But it is completely deepened on browser to send the referrer header,
so it may not work sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 2 way do it:

1. In your code, directed  www.domain-name.com/aboutus to  www.domain-name.com
2. Config webserver (apache, nginx)